# Can WidgetKit display gif images?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gif, widgetkit

As mentioned in Apple's official documentation,Starting with iOS 17, iPadOS 17, and macOS 14, widgets and Live Activities animate data updates with default animations or SwiftUI animations you choose, bringing a person’s attention to updated data.So i want to know can WidgetKit display gif images?

Display gif images on Widget.

Comment: I highly doubt it. However, you can achieve a similar effect by providing multiple timeline entries, each rendering a different static image (frame) and separated in time by the duration of a frame display time. Such "animation" will only play once. But bear in mind, that widget animation cannot exceed 2 seconds anyway.